# Turning Datalog queries in to SQL(ite) queries

Tags: sqlite, datalog

[Datalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog) is a lovely language for querying relational data. It is simple, clear, composes well, and supports recursive queries without additional syntax.

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org) is a fantastic embedded database with what seems to be a [powerful query engine](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) able to handle recursive queries – see the examples at the bottom of that page for generating Mandelbrot sets and finding all possible solutions to Sudoko puzzles!

I'm interested to know if there is a fairly standard way to translate from a datalog query in to recursive SQL as supported by SQLite, or if there are libraries that provide this facility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DLVDB is an interpreter for recursive Datalog that uses an ODBC database connection for their extensional data: http://www.dlvsystem.com/dlvdb/

Apart from that, the paper

S. Ceri, G. Gottlob, and L. Tanca. 1989. What You Always Wanted to Know About Datalog (And Never Dared to Ask). IEEE Trans. on Knowl. and Data Eng. 1, 1 (March 1989), 146-166. http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/69.43410

provides theoretical background and some pointers for translating Datalog into relational algebra.

Comment: Cool – thank you. I was hoping it'd be a few hundred lines of Lua or something. Oh well!